# Save extension's settings without "Save" button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I must click on button "save" If I want to accept any options for my chrome extension

[image]

How can I save extension's settings without "Save" button? (at once after checked any label or selected any option)

options.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
What to do?:
<select id="whattodo">
<option value="first">first action</option>
<option value="two">second action</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="testf">Test function
</label>
<br><br>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
<script src="options.js"></script>
</html>
```

options.js

```
function save_options() {
    var select1 = document.getElementById("whattodo");
    var whattodo = select1.children[select1.selectedIndex].value;
    chrome.storage.local.set({'whattodo': whattodo});

    if (document.getElementById('testf').checked) {
        localStorage.setItem('testf', "true");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('testf', "false");
    }

    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = "Options saved";
    setTimeout(function() {
        status.innerHTML = "";
    }, 750);
}
function restore_options() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('testf') == "true") {
        document.getElementById("testf").checked=true;
    } else {document.getElementById("testf").checked=false;}

    chrome.storage.local.get('whattodo', function(result) {
        var whattodo = result.whattodo;
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("whattodo").children.length; i++) {
            var child = document.getElementById("whattodo").children[i];
            if (child.value == whattodo) {
                child.selected = "true";
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click', save_options
```

);

Comment: You can listen to the `select` and `checkbox`'s [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) or [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event. And as both them will bubble, you can directly listen them from `body`, or create a container to wrap the inputs and listen to that container.

Comment: You could trigger the `save_options` function directly in the function that checks the labels and options. Or you could manually trigger the button by grabbing it from the DOM and using the `.click()` method.

Comment: @Shilly okay just `document.addEventListener('click', save_option)` :)

Comment: `document.querySelector('#save').click();` is what I meant with my last statement.